# Cannot read property 'blur' of null at nightmarejs

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, nightmare

I have been making simple code lately. however It's doesn't work.
why do that? I don't understand. I guess it didn't have error syntax.

but It occurred "Cannot read property 'blur' of null"

could you please help me?

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
nightmare = Nightmare({show: true});

nightmare.goto('https://www.google.com')
.type('form[action*="/search"] [name=f]', 'aa')
.click('form[action*="/search"] [type=submit]')
.then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);

})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue where DOM elements that are changed or removed during typing events can cause a similar problem.  It will be fixed in the next release of Nightmare.  See [#820](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/820) for details.  Quoting from the fix PR:

> If the element being typed or inserted into is removed from the DOM before the blur call is made (which can happen if the element is removed on a key event), an exception is raised. `blurSelector` now makes sure the element still exists before making the blur call. Also added a debug message if the selector does not exist after focusing.

Your script also appears to not be valid on the current incarnation of Google - have you also double-checked your selectors?